# prometheus operator helm chart failed to install due to prom admission serviceaccount error

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am trying to setup prometheus monitoring in Azure Kubernetes cluster.
Installed the [prometheus operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) using helm.

```
helm install prometheus-op-release stable/prometheus-operator --set global.rbac.create=false,prometheusOperator.serviceMonitor.interval=5s,alertmanager.enabled=false
```

After about 5 minutes, the installation timed out with below error,

> Error: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition

Looking into the cluster, noticed there is a new job `prometheus-op-release-prom-admission-create`
 created. It has a pod failing to create due to service account not found.

> Error creating: pods "prometheus-op-release-prom-admission-create-" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/prometheus-op-release-prom-admission: serviceaccount "prometheus-op-release-prom-admission" not found

Do I need to create the service account before installing the chart? Looking at the service account name, feel its dynamic and created as part of the chart installation. But am new to helm charts, not sure where to look for troubleshooting.

> kubectl version
>
> > **Client Version:** version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.2", GitCommit:"cff46ab41ff0bb44d8584413b598ad8360ec1def", GitTreeStat
> >     e:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-10T23:35:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
> >
> > **Server Version:** version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.8", GitCommit:"c52f59bbba5fbf21fbb18e9a06f96e563fe4c20a", GitTreeStat
> >     e:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-31T20:00:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
>
> helm version
>
> > version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.1", GitCommit:"afe70585407b420d0097d07b21c47dc511525ac8", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `global.rbac.create=false` from the helm command. If you specify this it will not automatically create the service account.

Comment: Yes, enabling rbac solved the problem.
There is a github issue https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/20825